# Writing an Craft plugin for imgix?

Tags: plugin-development

I have started using [imgix](https://www.imgix.com/) on some non-Craft sites, and it’s bloody awesome. It’s a bit similar to Craft in the way you apply transforms to a master image, and those transforms are done on-demand and then cached for future use. Only with imgix the transforms are done in the cloud and stored on their global CDN. Now I was thinking if it might be possible to write a Craft plugin to use imgix instead of the internal image handling code.

Any tips/pointers on how to go about this would be most appreciated!

Comment: I have a plugin to work with Imgix. Contact me if you want to test.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly seems doable to me. And the complexity would depend on how comfortable you are with PHP.

But roughly you'd follow the same format as the [Aviary Image Editor](https://github.com/fruitstudios/AviaryImageEditor) plugin for Craft where you have the user enter their imgix API key from their account and store that in the database. Then your plugin would be a wrapper for the [imgix API](https://docs.imgix.com/apis/url) calling their web service methods whenever you need to interact with them.

Answer (score 2):

I finally released a first version of the plugin: https://superbig.co/plugins/imgix